# Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory

Tags: magento2, database

I first install Magento in local host with xampp but after my installation i can't connect to my database and show me the following notice.
how to solve ?

> **There has been an error processing your request** Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root
>   directory.  The following modules are outdated: Magento_Customer data:
>   current version - none, required version - 2.0.6
>   Magento_BundleImportExport data: current version - none, required
>   version - 2.0.0

Error log record number: 740330652

Comment: Run command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`